# Where and how to set the variables for Percona MySQL Audit Variables

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5, percona

I am trying to set the variable values for Percona MySQL Audit Plugin in my.cnf file before installing the audit plugin on MySQL Server like 'audit_log_rotate_on_size','audit_log_rotations' and 'audit_log_file'.But MySQL is failing to install the plugin with the following error

ERROR 1123 (HY000): Can't initialize function 'audit_log'; Plugin initialization function failed.

Can any one tell me how to set the desired values for 'audit_log_rotate_on_size','audit_log_rotations' and 'audit_log_file' in the my.cnf file before installing the audit plugin on Percona MySQL.

I am using Percona MySQL Community Version 5.5.38

Comment: Is it possible that this is the issue, as described here? https://www.nowherelan.com/2014/01/18/mysql-enterprise-audit-error-plugin-audit_log-init-function-returned-error/
If so, there's info in that post on how to resolve this issue. Try that maybe?

Comment: I tried the ones mentioned in the link but no luck

Comment: Could you upload the results from: `SELECT * FROM mysql.plugin;`, your my.cnf file, and output from select version(); please?